# Move columns labels position

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, charts

I'm created a chart using the following code :

```
city_plt_piv.plot(figsize= (15,7) , use_index = 1);
```

But, as you can see in the attached image, the chart covered by "columns labels"
[image]

How to solve this issue and move it to another place, under or above the chart?

Comment: You have labeled this question both as `matlab` and `python` but you seem to seek an answer for python. Mind sharing your _whole_ code?

Comment: Both the code and the plot are definitely not from MATLAB, so I removed the tag.

Comment: I wanted to tag matplotlib , Matlab is my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this code

```
use_index = 1,secondary_y=['col b']).legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 1)
```

like this

```
city_plt_piv.plot(figsize= (15,15) , use_index = 1,secondary_y=['col b']).legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 1));
```

[image]